# How to get values from this data structure

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

An ajax request (stored in a variable named `results`) is returning this data as a response:

```
Object {hits: Object, links: Object}
  hits:Object
    hits:Array(2)
      0:Object
         active:true
         email:"user1@example.com"
         id:1
         links:Object
         __proto__:Object
      1:Object
         active:true
         email:"user2@example.com"
         id:2
         links:Object
         __proto__:Object
      length:2
      __proto__:Array(0)
      total:2
    __proto__:Object
  links:Object
__proto__:Object
```

What sort of data type it has? I thought it is json but using `JSON.parse(results)` returns this error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

How can I get access to the Array inside it? I need to get the email addresses and ids. It's probably not relevant but I'm using it in a ReactJS component.

Comment: It's already an object so you don't need to parse it. Use JSON.stringify if you want to get a string representation of the object.

Comment: Learn what JSON is (and is not) at json.org

Comment: How do you access anything in an object? `objectReference.property`...

Comment: Like 2085143 said, It is already an Json object. Json can be presented in two ways, one is json string on which you can call json.parse(), and the other one is json object on which you can call json.stringfy(). In your example, it looks the latter example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: ok you all are right. It is already a json object. So I tried to access the values but it fails. `results[‘hits']['hits']['0']`, `results['hits']['hits'][0]` or `results['hits'].hits.email` all fails with this error: `
uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined` . It recognizes the first `hits`, but not the second one

Comment: @Sarah did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

According your response, it's already a JSON object.
So if you want to access the *hits* property, here is the code: `results.hits`.

Also you mentioned the following:

> It recognizes the first hits, but not the second one.

Can you please try to `console.log(results.hits)` and share the output here? I guess your response object has only one *hits* property and it's type is array.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** As response is already a `JSON Object` so no need to Parse it again.

**Suggestion :** Use [**array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate the array and fetch the required elements.

**DEMO**

```js
var results = {
  "hits": {
  "hits": [
    {
      active:true,
      email:"user1@example.com",
      id:1
    },
    {
      active:true,
      email:"user2@example.com",
      id:2
    }
  ]
  },
  "links": {}
};

var res = results.hits.hits.map(function(item) {
  return item.email;
});

console.log(res);
```